# regexp get all prefix+word+postfix but without the exact word

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

EXAMPLE BELOW

## table a

```
id    desc  
0    qqqqqwertyyyy  
1    qwerty  
2    bbbbqwerty     
3    a qwerty
```

## desired output

```
0 qqqqqwertyyyy  
1 111qwerty
```

Comment: There is no question and the output does not match the input data.

Comment: I don't get this question. Where is the 'exact word' and where to match it?

Comment: exact word is 'qwerty' and 'a qwerty'. anyway ive found the answer thanks u guys

Answer (score 1):

You can break up the regex as:

[`\S+qwerty\b|\bqwerty\S+|\S+qwerty\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/YuzjMe/2)

This will match `qwerty` only when embedded in other word.

Comment: @jojo, Does `plsql` regex engine does not support the word boundary `\b` and the non-space character `\S`?. Please try: `[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]qwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: invalid character class in regular expression

Comment: From the link you provided, it seems that `\A` is the right choice for word boundary. So try the regex: `[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty\A|\Aqwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: None of the regular expressions in the answer or comments are valid in Oracle - `\b` is not valid in Oracle, `[:>:]` will match either `:` or `>` and [`[[:>:]]` is not a valid](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) POSIX character class. [`\A` matches only at the beginning of a string, or before a newline character at the end of a string](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix003.htm) so neither of those will work.

Comment: @MT0 Then a regex like `\bword\b` in javascript should be written as `\Aword\Z` in Oracle? If that is the case, the regex `[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty\Z|\Aqwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+|[0-9a-zA-Z]+qwerty[0-9a-zA-Z]+` should work.

Comment: No - `\A` and `^` are (almost) equivalent and `\Z` and `$` are (almost) equivalent. Oracle has no equivalent of `\b`.

Answer (score 1):

To match for prefix & postfix, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE    
    REGEXP_LIKE (fieldname, '[^[:space:]]+qwerty')
    OR  REGEXP_LIKE (fieldname, 'qwerty[^[:space:]]+');
```

Comment: i dont want to match the exact word qwerty here

Comment: Have u tried it out? `qwerty` won't be matched here. `'qwerty_%'` is a `prefix` match, as at least 1 or more characters are required after `qwerty` because of `_%`. `'%_qwerty'` is a postfix match, as at least 1 or more characters are required before `qwerty` because of `%_`.

Comment: yeah but it matches 'a qwerty'. What i need is to not match the exact word qwerty even with spaces

Comment: @jojo ok, I see. I edited my answer, feel free to try it.

Comment: This is wrong - `[^\s]` will match all characters that are not either the \ character or the `s` character. You can use `[^[:space:]]` POSIX character class instead.